# Sorting of dimension attribute values with translations

Tags: sql-server, sorting, internationalization, ssas, olap

I'm working on the translations of dimension attribute values to various languages. The goal is that user can dynamically change language of cube with all of texts in it. It's  working OK by simply binding column with translated texts to attribute via CaptionColumn.

However, the sorting is broken. It seems that only ordering by KeyColumn or ValueColumn works, but I need to sort by any of 42 translation columns. So if user changes language the sorting has to be done by corresponding language column.

I tried to play with collation of CaptionColumn but no success.

How to achieve this?